# Почему отображается зазор между клетками и как убрать его? (Шахматная доска)

Tags: html, css

```css
table
{
    width: 560px;
    height: 560px;
    border: 20px solid burlywood;
}
td
{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: white;
}
.firstRow>td:nth-child(even)
{

    background-color: black;
    border: none;
}
.secRow>td:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: black;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chess</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>
<table >
    <tr class="firstRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="secRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="secRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="secRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="secRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Используйте параметр `border-collapse` со значением =`collapse`.

```css
table
{
    border-collapse: collapse;
    width: 560px;
    height: 560px;
    border: 20px solid burlywood;
}
td
{
    width: 70px;
    height: 70px;
    background-color: white;
}
.firstRow>td:nth-child(even)
{

    background-color: black;
    border: none;
}
.secRow>td:nth-child(odd)
{
    background-color: black;
    border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Chess</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
</head>
<body>
<table >
    <tr class="firstRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="secRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="secRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="secRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="secRow">
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
        <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Альтернативное решение обнулить [border-spacing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/border-spacing)

```css
table {
  width: 560px;
  height: 560px;
  border: 20px solid burlywood;
  border-spacing: 0;
}
td {
  width: 70px;
  height: 70px;
  background-color: white;
}
.firstRow>td:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
}
.secRow>td:nth-child(odd) {
  background-color: black;
  border: none;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Chess</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="Style.css">
</head>

<body>
  <table>
    <tr class="firstRow">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="secRow">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstRow">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="secRow">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstRow">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="secRow">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="firstRow">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="secRow">
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
      <td></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</body>

</html>
```